# How switch tensorflow versions between 2.0 and 1.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Is there a way to switch versions of tensorflow?, when I installed tensorflow 2.0 using conda, it updated many things even python. On runing `conda list` it shows both versions;

> tensorflow  2.0.0   mkl_py37h66b46cc_0
>   tensorflow    1.13.1   < pip>

In order to use the 1.x version it's recommended [here](http://www.google.com/) to replace `import tensorflow as tf` for the following :
 
`import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()`
It is safe to use this method, just adding these lines?, in my case it shows a warning:
`WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/common/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/compat/v2_compat.py:65: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term`

Answer (score 3):

I would personally use two different virtual environments here. This would make sure you don't have dependency issues when using 2.0 vs 1.x. Conda environments are very easy to use. For example:

create the environment

```
conda create --tensorflow1
```

activate the environment

```
conda activate tensorflow1
```

When you have the environment activated you can conda/pip install TensorFlow 1.x and all dependencies will be contained within the environment. You can do the same thing with TensorFlow 2.0.

I can't comment on the above solution you have posted, but these are the cases where virtual environments are extremely useful.

Full docs here:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Thank's, can I run jupyter notebook in that virtual enviroment?

Comment: Yes, activate the environment and then launch Jupyter Notebook. I always do it from the command line.