# How to convert placeholder from Tensorflow 1.0 to tf.keras.input in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this line of code (for Tensorflow 1.0):

```
tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n, p])
```

`n` and `p` are just random numbers.

How to translate this line of code into `tf.keras.input` for Tensorflow 2.0?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583308/how-switch-tensorflow-versions-between-2-0-and-1-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

> Issue was resolved after creating two different virtual environments
> for `TF 2.x` and `1.x`.
>
> For more information you can refer detail answer mentioned by Denver
> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59583531/14290681).
>
> (paraphrased from lindo)

From Tensorflow documentation

In `TF 2.x`, you can just pass tensors directly into `ops` and `layers`. If you want to explicitly set up your inputs, you can see [Keras functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) on how to use [tf.keras.Input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) to replace  [tf.compat.v1.placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder). [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) arguments also do the job of `tf.compat.v1.placeholder`. For more details please read [Better performance with tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function).

`Input` produces a symbolic tensor-like object (i.e. a `placeholder`). This  can be used with lower-level TensorFlow ops that take tensors as inputs as shown below

```
x = Input(shape=(32,))
y = tf.square(x)  # This op will be treated like a layer
model = Model(x, y)
```

For more details you can refer [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)